# Unknown argument -swift while installation of firebase cocoapods in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

i have installed firebase cocoapods through terminal in my project , when i install the pods it shows me warning whether to use $ inherited in flags or remove target from build settings. I have tried both cases but i got an error of unknown argument -swift. when i remove the  $ inherited from other flags option in build settings it gives error on configuration of firebase, I'm stuck to this condition whole week but couldn't found any solution. My pods file is under a screenshot,
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your pod quotes are not as expected, open in a different text editor and edit them.

Change them as its here:

```
target 'PK.HouseUITests'
```

Comment: have to remove this target 'PK.HouseUITests' from pods file? @Burak Akyalçın

Comment: I don't think that will make a difference on installing pods

Comment: than what to write? @Burak Akyalçın

Comment: don't remove it. it installs pods for testing your project. just change quotes above.

Comment: can u please edit ur answer according to mine pods file what i had done mistake, actually i'm not getting how to write correctly my pods? @Burak Akyalçın

Comment: Just change that part:

pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

your quotes are wrong there, change them as I have written here